# setVisibility() is not refreshing the activity layout

Tags: android, visibility, android-theme, android-holo-everywhere

I am setting the visibility of a button as VISIBLE or GONE on spinner item selection:-

```
selectUserTypeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                FilterUserType newUserType = FilterUserType.get(position);
                if(filter.userType != newUserType){
                    filter.userType = newUserType;
                    ScrollView mainScrollView =  (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
                    switch (newUserType) {
                    case AnyUser:
                    case CurrentUser:{
                        selectUserBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        break;
                    }
                    case SpecificUser:{
                        selectUserBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}

        });
```

Here the problem is that my view is not refreshing after this action, but when I select one EditText on the page and keyboard is up.. at that time it refreshes and shows the desired behaviour.

I have tried editing switch-case as:-

```
switch (newUserType) {
    case AnyUser:
    case CurrentUser:{
        selectUserBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mainScrollView.invalidate();
        break;
    }
    case SpecificUser:{
        selectUserBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mainScrollView.invalidate();
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

But this is also not working

FYI, I am using `HoloEverywhere` theme in my project and this spinner is from HoloEverywhere widgets.

Comment: @auselen I have tried invalidating its parent view but it doesn't seem to work, can you please provide me with some code so that I can find out my mistake clearly.

Comment: @e7fendy selectUserBtn is the button displayed for users selection in the case of Specific User selection type, so it has no purpose to be visible on screen in any other case

Comment: actually I have tried debugging and the visibility values are changing on spinner action but they are not going visible until I select EditText and keyboard comes up.

Comment: call invalidate on root of the view you want to be redrawn.

Comment: Then we need more code to help you.

Comment: this is all the code I have in my activity.. just 1 important thing to note is that I am using HoloEverywhere

Comment: I have edited the questing to show what is not working

Comment: You need to show us how you initialize `selectUserBtn`

Comment: I am setting my `contentView` in `onCreate` of this activity, `selectUserBtn` is there in the layout xml and I am retrieving it by findViewById just before setting the click listener of spinner in `OnCreate`

Comment: I tried your code on AVDs with Android 2.3 and 4.2 and it works how you want. Which device or AVD you use for testing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem. The spinner class from holoeverywhere updates its graphics after the onItemSelected is called. So it "overrides" your layout update. The only solution I found was to set a handler to update the ui, to be exececuted 1 second in the future.
Like this:

```
Handler han = new Handler();
        han.postAtTime(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // UPDATE UI HERE
            }
        }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution anno 2022 is using the following method:

```
runOnUiThread(() -> mBoatSelectMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE));
```

Where mBoatSelectMenu the referred XML id is of the chosen element.